# Determining The Complete Size Of A Folder & Its Sub-Folders in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

Simply how do I see the complete size of a folder within Finder ?

(AFAIK there is no default setting to automatically turn this feature on - correct me if i'm wrong)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Finder:

1. Either:

   1. <kbd>Option</kbd> + click a folder.
   2. *Or:* Click the gear icon in the header.
   3. *Or:* Select the View menu, and then "Show View Options".
   4. *Or:* <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
2. Select "Show View Options"
3. In the 4th subset of options select the box "Calculate all sizes".

*If a folder is empty it will only show "--" like all the folders previously did.*

[image]

Comment: The skitch is strong in that bassplayer7 one :-)

Comment: @bmike Clarify "skitch" - do you mean his annotation in red ?

Comment: @Simon [Skitch](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch/id425955336?mt=12) (and [Napkin](http://aged-and-distilled.com/napkin/) is even more awesome than Skitch in many respects…)

Comment: @bmike Ah yes I think it was bought by Evernote, and then because people "complained", Evernote released it as a stand-alone product again recently

Comment: @bmike Ah ok thanks for informing me. I know about Skitch but when you said it above I thought it was some american word i'd never heard of :)

Comment: @bmike, totally. I (used to) love Skitch for SE screenshots. The problem is the drag and drop function no longer works. :-( I have to save -> upload it now. I'll have to check Napkin out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use quick look on a folder (just select a folder and hit spacebar). This will calculate the complete size of the folder just once.